# Getting out of memory issue in jmeter non gui mode

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0, jmeter-4.0, jmeter-3.2

created a script with this configuration:
Number of threads (users) - 200 users
Duration assertion - 3 seconds
Ramp-up period - 10 seconds
Think time - 2 seconds

Jmeter version 5.2.1
Java 8

Laptop configuration:
Microsoft windows 10
Intel i7 processor
RAM 16gb

I also increased the size of the memory to 1024m in batch file

: "${HEAP:="-Xms1g -Xmx1g -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=1024m"}"

Still I am facing the out of memory issue. can you please help me out

Answer (score 1):

As per [Java command line arguments](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/java.html#BABHDABI)

> **-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=size**
>
> Sets the maximum amount of native memory that can be allocated for class metadata. **By default, the size is not limited.** The amount of metadata for an application depends on the application itself, other running applications, and the amount of memory available on the system.

So if you're getting `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Metaspace` error you need to either increase the metaspace size more or just remove this parameter from the JVM arguments so it will be unlimited.

Most probably you're getting `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`, if this is the case - you need to increase the `-Xmx1g` to somewhat bigger, i.e. `-Xmx4g`

[Actually OutOfMemoryError exception has many faces](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/memleaks002.html) so it's not possible to provide exact steps for  this without seeing the full output from [stdout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_(stdout))/[stderr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_error_(stderr))/[jmeter.log](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) file/ [.hprof file](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/360033184011-KBEC-00423-How-to-configure-HPROF-files-and-generation-and-details-on-how-to-Analyze-Hprof-files)

See [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure) article for more JMeter tuning tips.

Comment: I'm getting this error  -   uncaught exception java.lang.outofmemoryerror unable to create new native thread

Comment: As per your comments it should like this right?                         : "${HEAP:="-Xms4g -Xmx4g -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=512m"}"

Comment: You can leave `Xms1g` bit, with regards to ramping up the upper limit to 4 gigabytes - I don't know, hopefully it will be enough.